# mailx not found in alpine

Tags: alpine-linux, mailx

I am very new to docker and alpine-linux. I have a bash script that runs great in RHEL VM. I am trying to make this run in a alpine-linux v3.11 docker container.
My bash script currently uses curl, jq, mailx. To cover these dependencies I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk update && \
    apk add bash vim curl jq mailx
```

Build shows `Installing mailx (8.1.1-r1)`

However, in the container, I cannot see mailx.

```
/ # mailx
/bin/sh: mailx: not found
/ # which mailx
/ #
```

Can someone provide help on how to get mailx working in alpine-linux?
I can change my bash script to use other email options in alpine-linux, but my first preference was to have it run as-is in alpine-linux.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the executable in Alpine's mailx package is actually just `mail`.

See [contents of mailx package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=edge&name=mailx&arch=x86_64&repo=main), which is comprised of:

- `/etc/mail.rc`
- **`/usr/bin/mail`**
- `/usr/share/misc/mail.tildehelp`
- `/usr/share/misc/mail.help`

Comment: Thanks. mailx on RedHat provides the option of -S (to provide an external smtp server) and 'mail' on Alpine (executable of mailx) does not seem to provide the option.

Comment: @RaghavendraChannappa Alpine typically ships bare bones versions of most packages. You can try something like [ssmtp](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/ssmtp) as an SMTP sender, but it'll probably take some tweaking to put it all together. I suggest you ask a separate question about how to send mail out from Alpine. Consider asking at Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, you may get better answers there.